# Does sequential consistency imply causal consistency?

Tags: concurrency, distributed-system

Using the following definitions of sequential consistency and causal consistency:

Sequential consistency: The result of any execution is the same as if the (read and write) operations by all processes on the data store were executed in some sequential order and the operations of each individual process appear in this sequence in the order specified by its program.

Causal consistency: Writes that are potentially causally related must be seen by all processes in the same order. Concurrent writes may be seen in a different order on different machines.

From these definitions, would it be correct to say that any sequentially consistent system is also causally consistent? I can not think of any counterexample of a sequentially consistent system that is not also causally consistent. Any sequential ordering of events seemingly is causally consistent.